# Angular 5 Can't get directive inside of ng-template from directive placed on item in a list

Tags: angular

am trying to create a reusable list with an optional "grip" directive on each item

See this Plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/AaKbi4bOUO3gNJ0xEeJc?p=preview

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[grip]'
})
export class Grip { }

@Directive({
  selector:'[item]'
})
export class ListItem{

  @ContentChild(Grip) grip: Grip; <-- UNDEFINED
}

@Component({
  selector:'[list]',
  template: `
  <div item *ngFor="let item of items"
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ item: item }">
 </div>
 `
})
export class List{

  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) template: TemplateRef<any>;
  @Input() items: any[]
}
```

usage

```
<div list [items]="[0,1,2]">
  <ng-template let-item="item">
    <span grip>#</span>
    <span>{{item}}</span>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

looks like the innermost directive is being created, but the ContentChild in the ListItem is not hooked up